# Issue with git merge/squash wtih .gitignore

Tags: git, merge, git-merge, rebase, git-rebase

I have 2 previous commits I would like to combine into a 1, both of which are .gitignore

First commit of `.gitignore`:

```
  /Download/SoccerNet
  /Download/BWF TV/**/*.mp4
  /Download/Badminton Video Data (youtube-dl, unlabeled)
+ /Dataset/SoccerNet
+ /Dataset/Badminton/BWF TV/**/*.mp4
+ /Dataset/Badminton/Youtube (unlabeled)
+ /Tutorials (youtube-dl)
```

Second commit of `.gitignore`:

```
  # NEW
+ <<<<<<< HEAD
  /Download/SoccerNet
  /Download/BWF TV/**/*.mp4
  /Download/Badminton Video Data (youtube-dl, unlabeled)
+ =======
+ >>>>>>> cd75117 (Add .gitattributes, Edit .gitignore)
  /Dataset/SoccerNet
  /Dataset/Badminton/BWF TV/**/*.mp4
  /Dataset/Badminton/Youtube (unlabeled)
```

When running `git rebase -i <first-commit-SHA>`, then editting the rebase file as:

```
pick <first-commit-SHA> <message1>
s <second-commit-SHA> <message2>
```

I get error:

```
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
        .gitattributes
Please commit your changes or stash them before you merge.
Aborting
hint: Could not execute the todo command
hint:
hint:     pick ff23b6f067d253ffd8f5865ba99973d69bc1904e .gitignore, .gitattributes
hint:
hint: It has been rescheduled; To edit the command before continuing, please
hint: edit the todo list first:
hint:
hint:     git rebase --edit-todo
hint:     git rebase --continue
```

I don't see why these two `.gitignore` instances can't be squashed together.

Comment: You have uncommitted work in the file named `.gitattributes`. Your second commit affects (probably, by creating from nothing) the file `.gitatttributes`. This will overwrite the uncommitted work in `.gitattributes`. Git is telling you to save that work somewhere first.

Comment: Ah you're right. I initialied Git LFS later on and so `.gitattributes` didn't exist back in these commits. Thank you!